# Помочь Переделать запрос к бд

Tags: php, mysqli

имеется вот такой запрос к базе данных

```
$list = database::i()->support('user_id = ?', $user_id)->limit('10')->order('created_at DESC');
```

Он берет последние 10 записей с таблицы support и выводит в виджет, но получается так, что самые последние сообщения оказываются в самом верху, а поле ввода находиться в низу, может кто то сможет помочь соорудить конструкцию подобную этому?

```
$list = database::query("SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM support ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 10) tmp ORDER BY created_at ASC");
```

Что бы последние записи были выведены циклом последними, а не как первыми.

Всем спасибо!

Comment: Я так понимаю, что, наверное, `order('created_at DESC');` нужно заменить на `order('created_at ASC');`

Comment: Тогда оно начнет сортировать с начала таблицы, а мне нужно вывести последних 10 записей, и что бы последняя была в цике выведена последней, а она выводиться первой, пример как работает ниже $list = database::query("SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM support ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 10) tmp ORDER BY created_at ASC");

Но он выводит только один параметр данных, а самый верхний запрос, все данные в таблице

Comment: Ну так в виджете своем идите с конца массива и выводите записи.

Comment: @YaroslavDomen $list=array_reverse($list) ?

Comment: Спасибо, попробую

Answer (score 0):

Вам не нужно делать подобные вещи запросами к БД. Обработка данных должна происходить на контроллере.

Если результат выполнения `database::i()->support->...` - массив, то просто пройдитесь по нему в обратном порядке:

```php
for ($i = count($list) - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
    echo ($list[$i]);
}
```

Если `$list` - объект, то советую посмотреть документацию к ORM, которую вы используете, возможно она уже имеет методы для получения строк результата запроса в обратном порядке.
Если нет, то, скорее всего, `$list` реализует интерфейсы `\Iterator, \ArrayAccess, \Countable`, и вы сможете работать с ним как с массивом.

Если на чистом mysqli, то как то так:

```php
$query = "SELECT * FROM support ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 10";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
    $rows_count = $result->num_rows;

    $list = array();
    // Идем по циклу от последней строки к перовй
    for ($i = $rows_count - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
        // смещаем указатель на нужную строку
        $result->data_seek($i);

        // получаем строку
        $list[] = $result->fetch_row();
    }

    $result->close();
}

var_dump($list);
```